Modify Access query in VB.net using QueryDef causes query to run slower
I modify the following query SQL by changing the WHERE clause value and use the query QueryDef.SQL to save the changes. Before doing the update the query runs very fast but after it is much slower. The tables are indexed on the WHERE clause field (LoadID). What can I do to modify the query as I need and not affect the speed?
I need to edit the query saved in Access because I then run a report via DoCmed that uses this query.
My code that does the modification:
qdfLoop = db.QueryDefs("" & theQueryName & "")

qdfLoop.SQL = theQuerySQL

SELECT
    Clients.TheName AS ClientName,
    LoadStops.LoadID,
    LoadStops.Stop,
    OrderDetail.ProbillNumber,
    OrderHeader.ClientOrderNumber,
    OrderDetail.DeliveryPO,
    Format([LoadStops].[Arrived],"mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn") AS Arrived,
    Format([LoadStops].[Departed],"mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn") AS Departed, 
    Locations.TheName
FROM
    (Locations INNER JOIN (((LoadStops INNER JOIN LoadDetails ON (LoadStops.Stop = LoadDetails.Stop) AND (LoadStops.LoadID = LoadDetails.LoadID)) INNER JOIN OrderDetail ON (LoadDetails.Item = OrderDetail.Item) AND (LoadDetails.ProbillNumber = OrderDetail.ProbillNumber)) INNER JOIN OrderHeader ON OrderDetail.ProbillNumber = OrderHeader.ProbillNumber) ON Locations.TheID = LoadStops.Location) INNER JOIN Clients ON OrderHeader.ClientID = Clients.TheID
WHERE
    (((LoadStops.LoadID)=146403))
ORDER BY
    Format([LoadStops].[Arrived],"mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn");


Ahhh, I sure don't miss the FROM clause of an Access query designer. "Need. More. Parenthesis!!!"

ORDER BY Format() seems both wrong and slow. It will group months together across years. And if all the results are in the same year, then just order by the column without needing to format it. Also, I went to HS with a John Lee many years ago.
